# Comparing consecutive elements in a queue

Tags: match, equality, priority-queue, element

I have a queue of elements, sorted by date. I need to extract the first n elements, which have the same date and add them to a temporary ArrayList, from which I choose one of them and scrap the others. After that I need to continue doing the same thing for the next n elements of the queue with the same date (extract them to the temp list and so on) until I have no more items in the queue.

```
        // some notes to help you understand the code
        PriorityQueue<Results> r, size(4), elementsEqualByTime(1=2,3=4); 
        List<Comments> c, size(2);
        ArrayList temp;

        if (c.size() != r.size() && resultIter.hasNext()) {
        //first iteration will compare element 0 to itself -> 100% true
           ResultObject r2 = resultIter.next();
           ResultObject r1 = r2;

        while (resultIter.hasNext() && r1.getTime().equals(r2.getTime())) {
            temp.add(r1);
            //we add the matching elements before we continue
            r1 = r2;
            temp.add(r1);
              if (resultIter.hasNext()) {
            //after we add the 2 matching elements we continue
                   r2 = resultIter.next();
                }
            }
            //use the items in temp
                   temp.clear();
        }
```

Right now it works for the 1st set of elements, but on the 2nd iteration it adds no elements to the temp ArrayList. I'd appreciate help with this solution, but am also open to different suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  while (commentIter.hasNext()) {

        Comment c1 = null;

        temp.add(arrayQueue[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < arrayQueue.length; i++) {
            if (!arrayQueue[i].getTime().equals(arrayQueue[i - 1].getTime())) {

                c1 = commentIter.next();
                //do stuff with the results                 
                temp = new HashSet<ResultObject>();

            }
            temp.add(arrayQueue[i]);
        }

        if (!temp.isEmpty()) {

            c1 = commentIter.next();
            //do stuff with the results
        }
        temp = new HashSet<ResultObject>();
    }
```

That's a tested solution which works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean Check (List<Element> elements,Element element)
    {
        for(Element element1:elements)
            if(element1.equals(element))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
     void Stuff()
{

    // some notes to help you understand the code
    PriorityQueue<Element> r = new PriorityQueue<Element>();
    List<Element> c;
    List<Element> temp = new ArrayList<Element>();

    for(Element element:r)
    {
            if(!Check(temp, element))
            {
                // do stuff with temp
                temp = new ArrayList<Element>(); 
            }
            temp.add(element);
        } 
}
```